# How to Distinguish CSB app from hosted CSB

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a standalone Client-Side Blazor app (CSB) that can optionally be hosted (CSBhosted).  Both run the identical WASM app in the browser. Now I'd like to know if the client app can make server REST calls; CSBhosted can, CSB can't.

**Edit:**
OR, just say I'd like to display a string that says "Hosted App" or "Standalone App".

So what's the easiest way to tell if the client app is hosted or not?

Comment: Short answer yes your stand alone CSB can call API's. If its not working it is configuration of either security or cors. I have a standalone CSB that auths against ID4 and calls a seperate gateway api... Without seeing any of your code we cannot help.

Comment: You describe two apps and then ask about 'the' app. Not clear.

Comment: @Brian yeah, I could just make the REST call and catch errors but I was hoping a simpler method.  For example I would like to set `IsHosted=true` and run some initialization code.

Comment: @Brian Also, this problem is not about making api calls (of course the standalone CSB can make 3rd party api calls). It's about configuring the app differently depending on if it is hosted or not.  Let's just say I want to display a string that says "Hosted App" or "Standalone App".

Comment: @Henk Sure. Any suggestions on what "configure something" could be? Neither appsettings.json nor launchSettings will work.

Comment: host name is arbitrary...